# Unexpected T_VARIABLE error

Tags: php, include, variables

Okay, I know this is a common enough question, but all the solutions I've found thus far have involved a missing semi-colon or curly brace, both of which I know is not the case for me.

I have a class that works FINE with this variable assignment:

**session.php:**

```
<?php

   class session {
     ... 
     var $host = 'localhost';
     ...
   }

?>
```

Great. But I want to have my database details in another file, so I did this:

**db_creds.php:**

```
<?php

   var $db_creds = array(
      'host' => 'localhost',
      ...
   );

?>
```

**session.php**

```
<?php

   include('db_creds.php');

   class session {
     ... 
     var $host = $db_creds['host'];
     ...
   }

?>
```

Which then gave me this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in ../session.php on line 74`, where line 74 is my `var $host` assignment.

I even tried doing this in **session.php**, just to be sure the problem wasn't in the include:

**session.php**

```
<?php

   # include('db_creds.php');

   class session {
     ...
     var $db_host = 'localhost';
     var $host = $db_host;
     ...
   }

?>
```

... but that just throws the same error as above.

Can anyone tell me what's happening here? I'm at my wits end!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Variables are not allowed here, properties must be initialized by constants in PHP:

> […] this initialization must be a constant value

[[Source: php.net manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)]

Use the constructor to intialize the value properly:

```
class session {
    var $host;

    function __construct() {
        $this->host = $db_creds['host'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, got it. Still new to PHP classes and whatnot. Thanks! +1

Answer (score -1):

1. the first letter in a class name should be capital (class Session)
2. did you write a constructor
3. class properties are accessed with $this->property

Comment: -1 Point 1 is subjective, and points 2 and 3 are irrelevant to the OP's problem.