# Issue with wrapping server variable arrays (e.g., $_POST, $_GET)

Tags: php, arrays, session, post, get

Say I have defined a couple of classes like this:

```
abstract class ServerVars {
  public static function get($k) {
    if (empty($arr[$k])) throw new Exception('Not found');
    return $arr[$k]; // Also include error checking
  }
  public static function set($k, $v) {
    $arr[$k] = $v;
  }
  ... // Other useful methods
}

public class Session extends ServerVars {
  static $arr = $_SESSION; // !!!
  public static function destroy() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Basically, I am just trying to wrap certain server variables like $_SESSION, $POST, etc. to make my code a bit more modular. But the line marked with `!!!` causes the error `unexpected '$_SESSION' (T_VARIABLE)`. Why does this error occur? And is there a better way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694378/unexpected-t-variable-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initializer for a class variable has to be constant. `$_SESSION` is a variable, which is not necessarily constant.

Don’t use inheritance for this; it’s wholly inappropriate. If you insist on having a class, it should be one class:

```
class DuplicatesBuiltInFunctionality {
    public function __construct($arr) {
        $this->arr = $arr;
    }

    public function get($k) {
        if(!isset($this->arr[$k])) throw new Exception('Not found');
        return $this->arr[$k];
    }

    public function set($k, $v) {
        $this->arr[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why's it inappropriate? In my case, it seems like a useful abstraction. Doing it your way, I'd have to create instances, which doesn't seem right, since I only need one instance for the entire program (and I'm trying to avoid using the singleton pattern). All I'm wondering is how to get my particular code to work.

Comment: @Intredasting: No, you don’t need one instance for the entire program. You need one for `$_SESSION`, one for `$_POST` (and I’m assuming you were planning on doing the same thing for `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`).

Comment: But if I wind up saying $post = new DuplicatesBuiltInFunctionality($_POST), and I use that in one function, then in another function defined in some other script I'm requiring, I won't be able to use that $post variable; I'd need to instantiate another one.

Comment: @Intredasting: Use the `global` keyword.